# Flutter Wireless Debugging - Debugger won't start

Tags: flutter, debugging, adb

[image]

So, I have connected to my phone using the `adb connect` command and now everything is going fine. Only issue is after a successful connection and the `assembleDebug` process the `flutter run` just get stuck. It's like the debugger is not able to start for some reason. Did anyone face an issue like this ?

```
System Info: 

Flutter SDK Version: Flutter 3.0.2
Device Model: Samsung Galaxy M31
CPU Architecture: Android ARM64
Android Version: Android 12
```

If yes, I would like to know how you made your way around it. Any help is appreciated ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not post terminal output as screenshot, instead just copy the content and paste it into your question.

Comment: oh okay, I will keep that in mind next time. Thanks !